# How can i stop my windows 10 mail app that pop-ups continuously forcing me to add account?

Tags: windows-10, email, services, popups, windows-10-mail-app

I am having an issue with the built-in Mail app service in Windows 10. It continuously pop-ups by asking to add an account. When added an account, it now asks to re-enter the password. Still, each time I close the mail window, it appears over all the other apps continuously.

[image: Pop-up image]]

I tried the following solutions:

1. In the default-apps settings for Windows 10, set the default app for Email as Google chrome instead of the built-in recommended Mail app. But this made the problem worst as an infinite number of google chrome windows continuously opened up.
2. Removed the mail app package via PowerShell with the following command. But this automatically sets the google chrome as default Email app and the issue still persists.

`Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps | Remove-AppxPackage`

3. Tried adding a mail account. But problem not solved.
4. Installed the latest windows updates and restarted the system
5. Disabled all the permissions for the Mail and calendar app
6. Reset the Mail app

None of the solutions worked. Can I disable this Email service of windows 10?

Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the actual problem. There is a mail key on my peripheral keyboard. The issue was keyboard ghosting. Maybe the mail key was jammed. That's why it triggered the repeated opening of the 'default' mail app, whatever be it.

Remove the dust inside the keyboard to fix the jammed key: https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Jammed-Keyboard-Key

Or replacing keyboard solves the issue.